# How to style TexField Component with type = date on React JS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have installed a component from material-ui/core/TextField. But I can't change the color of date Picker element.

```
       <TextField
                    id="date"
x                   label="Início "
                     type="date"
                     multiline={false}
                     defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                     InputLabelProps={{
                     color:'secondary',
                     className:"DatePicker",
                     style : {color:"#ffff",},
                     shrink: true,}}/>
```

[image: Demonstration of the result I have at the moment]

this way it only changes the label , but not the date itself , neither the small calendar icon.
I would like to change the color of the black date and calendar icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `inputProps`.

```js
<TextField
  id="date"
  label="Início "
  type="date"
  multiline={false}
  defaultValue="2017-05-24"
  InputLabelProps={{
    color: "secondary",
    className: "DatePicker",
    style: { color: "#ffff" },
    shrink: true,
  }}
  inputProps={{
    style: { color: "#ffff" },
  }}
/>;
```

Resource - https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

Comment: yes, it only work for the label "início" not the date and the small calendar icon :/

Comment: you're talking about `InputLabelProps`. Check my version. It's `inputProps`